# PHP: Changing date format always returns 01-01-1970 or error

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to convert a date in PHP from "04-13-2023" (m-d-Y) to "13-04-2023" (d-m-Y).
When I print these:

```
print_r("dispatch_date: " . $dispatch_date);
    $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dispatch_date)); 
print_r("date: " . $newDate);
    $newDate2 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y',$dispatch_date);
print_r("date2: " . $newDate2);
    exit;
```

I get:

dispatch_date: 04-13-2023
date: 01-01-1970

and for the last one the following error:
Uncaught Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string in (...)

I have been looking at similar questions/answer for a couple of hours now but still could not figure it out.

Comment: Problem 2 - `$newDate2` is an object Use `$newDate2->format()` or a simple `print_r($newDate2);`

Comment: Big Note `01-01-1970` always means you did something wrong

Comment: Problem 1 - Use `/` instead of `-` to make it come under [`acceptable date notations`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). See https://3v4l.org/rDlmq

Comment: `echo $newDate2->format('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime, looks at the seperators to decide if its a sensible date format or a USA date format. `/` is interpreted as US `-` as rest of world

A [datetime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) has a `->format()` method to output the date however you want to see it.

```
$dispatch_date = '04-13-2023';

print_r("dispatch_date: " . $dispatch_date);
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(str_replace('-','/',$dispatch_date))); 
print_r("date: " . $newDate);

$newDate2 = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y',$dispatch_date);
echo 'Date2 ' . $newDate2->format('Y-m-d');
```

RESULTS

```
dispatch_date: 04-13-2023
date: 13-04-2023

Date2 2023-04-13
```

Comment: The str_replace solved it, thanks a lot!